# Python __subclasses__() not listing subclasses

Tags: python

I cant seem to list all derived classes using the `__subclasses__()` method. Here's my directory layout:

```
import.py
backends
      __init__.py
    --digger
          __init__.py
          base.py
          test.py
        --plugins
              plugina_plugin.py
```

From `import.py` i'm calling `test.py`. `test.py` in turn iterates over all the files in the `plugins` directory and loads all of them. `test.py` looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import re

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( __file__ )))))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( __file__ ))), 'plugins'))

from base import BasePlugin

class TestImport:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'heeeeello'

        PLUGIN_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( __file__ ))), 'plugins')

        for filename in os.listdir (PLUGIN_DIRECTORY):
            # Ignore subfolders
            if os.path.isdir (os.path.join(PLUGIN_DIRECTORY, filename)):
                continue
            else:
                if re.match(r".*?_plugin\.py$", filename):
                    print ('Initialising plugin : ' + filename)
                    __import__(re.sub(r".py", r"", filename))

        print ('Plugin system initialized')
        print BasePlugin.__subclasses__()
```

The problem us that the `__subclasses__()` method doesn't show any derived classes. All plugins in the `plugins` directory derive from a base class in the `base.py` file.

`base.py` looks like this:

```
class BasePlugin(object):
    """
    Base
    """
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

`plugina_plugin.py` looks like this:

from base import BasePlugin

```
class PluginA(BasePlugin):
    """
    Plugin A
    """
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Could anyone help me out with this? Whatm am i doing wrong? I've racked my brains over this but I cant seem to figure it out

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see the message `Initialising plugin : plugina_plugin`?

Comment: Yeah. It pops up. It seems that the class even gets imported but the `__subclasses__` method doesn't list it for some reason.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. `print BasePlugin.__subclasses__()` yields `[<class 'test3.PluginA'>]`. Perhaps if you copy the directory structure and keep paring down the code to its simplest possible form (with each change testing if problem remains), at some intermediate stage you'll find a clue as to the source of the problem. For example, get rid of all extraneous code in test.py, simplify the directory structure, get rid of import.py, etc...

Comment: What is your OS, and what is the python version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were no other base.py files. I'm on a WinXP (SP2) with Python 2.6. I added another class to my `test.py` file called `PluginB` which used `BasePlugin` as the base class. When i did

```
    print PluginA.__mro__
    print PluginB.__mro__
```

I got:

```
(<class 'plugina_plugin.PluginA'>, <class 'base.BasePlugin'>, <type 'object'>)
(<class 'backends.digger.test.PluginB'>, <class 'backends.digger.base.BasePlugin'>, <type 'object'>)
```

As you can see, they're both using the same base plugin but the qualified names are different. This was because in `plugina_plugin.py` I was importing `BasePlugin` like this:

```
from base import BasePlugin
```

Instead of:

```
from backends.digger.base import BasePlugin
```

Fixing this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for digging through this issue! Who would've thought that an object with two different qualified names has two independent aliases!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the plugins are finding another `base.py` hiding somewhere (the plugin directory for example).
Run with `python -v` to see if two different `base.py` are getting imported

You can also look at `PluginA.__mro__` and confirm that the `BasePlugin` in there is the right one