# Splitting factory, super and subs out from a single module

Tags: python

I have a working module that contains a factory function, a super class and two sub classes.  The actual module is [here](https://github.com/natemarks/CiscoXMLPexpect/blob/master/CiscoXMLPexpect/commandler.py).

I split the factory into its own file and put the two subclasses into the  commands/ directory so I could get around a recursion problem caused by importing my subs in the module containing my super.

Just when I think I have everything importing correctly, the factory is stuck with an empty list of subclasses when I try:

```
for cls in Command.__subclasses__():
```

Comment: Have any of the Command sub-classes actually been imported at the point where you look at the list?

Comment: Note: `__subclassess__` is a CPython optimization detail. Do not rely on it as a language feature.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048337/python-subclasses-not-listing-subclasses it seems `__subclasses__()` is quite finicky, in addition to being implementation dependent as @MartijnPieters points out.  Have you thought about giving a `metaclass` a try?  I've never seen these sorts of issues when using one to register subclasses to a factory or other construct.

Comment: thanks for all the feedback.  the classes seemt o be importing.  the factory function can print the value of Command.__name__.  I don't know if the subclasses are failing tob e imported or if the Command.__subclasses__ is just not valid after I move things around.

Comment: I 'll have to do some research on an alternative to using _subclasses__.  an alternative might also provide a solution:)

Comment: I'm going to mark this as solved because metaclasses are probably the tool for the job.  That said, they're fairly inaccessible  to the novice. If I figure it out, I'll try to document the comparison of my original, lazy but convenient use of __subclasses__ to the probably more effective use of metaclasses.

Comment: @mnate: it's not "marked as solved" unless you post your (best) solution as an answer, and then select it by clicking the green check mark near the up/downvote buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty but it works.  I'd love a more elegant way to convert the string to the class name.  looping through __subclasses__ was indeed too finicky.  I just don't understand metaclass well enough to apply it.

```
from commands.shVersionCmd import shVersionCmd
from commands.shVRFCmd import shVRFCmd
def CommandFactory(commandnode):
    if commandnode.attrib['name'] == 'shVersionCmd': return shVersionCmd(commandnode)        
    if commandnode.attrib['name'] == 'shVRFCmd': return shVRFCmd(commandnode)
```